# How can I detect a selectable static text field in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have selectable static text fields in my flash project and I need to detect them as targets on `MOUSE_MOVE` event. I know it can be difficult to detect `StaticText` class, but if a static text field is `selectable`, it becomes `TextField` class. Dynamic text, which is also TextField class, is easy to detect, but when it comes to selectable static text, I can't get this working. When I try to trace `event.target` on `MOUSE_MOVE` event, it doesn't trace anything if I hover the mouse over a selectable static text field (if it's a dynamic text field, I get [object TextField]). Why do dynamic text and selectable static text , which are the same class, behave so differently? And how can I detect selectable static text on `MOUSE_MOVE` or `MOUSE_OVER` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why cant you set it dynamic? Static and dynamic both extend TextField. But have the attributes set different. In this case dynamic text has mouseEnabled set to true and static has it set to false. And doesnt listen to mouseEvents in general.

Edit:
you can type html text in dynamic TextField -> [htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)

Comment: I need static text because it allows to format separate words differently from the other text in the same text field. If I try to make one word bold with dynamic text, it makes all the words bold.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the reference for the StaticText class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html#eventSummary it does not dispatch any `MouseEvent` events, therefore it is impossible to listen for `MOUSE_MOVE` events on static text fields. What you can do is follow one of the suggestions proposed the last time you asked this question: [How can I detect StaticText in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226432/how-can-i-detect-statictext-in-as3)

Comment: As I already said, when you make static text selectable, it becomes the TextField class, which should behave differently from the StaticText class.

Comment: While it does appear that setting it as selectable causes a static text field to report itself as a member of the `TextField` class, it still will not dispatch any `MouseEvent` events. M4tchB0X3r's suggestion to use a dynamic field instead may be the way to go, unless you plan on using subscript or superscript text which is unsupported in dynamic textfields. As they advised, if you set the textfield to allow html text, you will be able to format words individually.